# Jquery doesn't apply hide() to all of the divs with the same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a site, and the html is displayed through php with data fetched from a database.
I have a foreach() function, so all of the things displayed have the same DIV ID's.
It ends up being like 4 DIVs with the same ID (#content), so the PHP works fine, but I have a jQuery script and when I call the  `jQuery("#content").hide();` it only hides ONE of the DIV's not all of them, and I want it to hide all of them. Is there something else I have to do?
Thanks.

Comment: some references: [html4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) *This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.* - [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) *The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID).*

Comment: For debugging purpose, you should test your pages in an HTML validator like http://validator.w3.org/ (or install an extension like the Web Developer Toolbar in Firefox or an equivalent one in Chrome; the entry Tools/Validate HTML will submit your page to the validator). A valid code can automagically solve problems like this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a class (`.class_name`), not an id--only one DOM element may have a given ID, otherwise it's invalid HTML. It's reasonable for an ID selector to return only a single element.

Answer (score 2):

IDs on elements on a page should be unique. So every HTML tag you specify should have a different ID. If you want to hide all of a certain element, it might be suitable to add a class to the elements you wish to hide?

e.g.

```
<div class="divToHide">Content...</div>
<div class="divToHide">Content...</div>
<div class="divToHide">Content...</div>
```

Then your jquery would be:

```
$(".divToHide").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's simply because you cannot have more than one element with a specified ID. IDs are and must be unique. Only one single element with the same element may exist in a DOM.

Failing to follow this rule may result in broken scripts and other horrors.

You can use classes for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

an ID can only be used **ONCE** in HTML! because its a id and a id should always be Unique